# Data-structure to use for sentence comparison

Tags: string, data-structures

I'll try to be as succinct as possible as this will require some explanation. I am in a situation where I have to match strings, and extract values from those strings based on template strings that we define.

For example, the template sting would be:

> I want to go to the $websiteurl homepage

And the other string could be

> I want to go to the google.com homepage

We've had initial success checking that these strings match by measuring Levenshtein Distances and by using "creative" regular expressions, but we're trying to grow this to be more fault tolerant and accurate and the amount of complicated code is growing more than we would like.

Some scenarios we need to check compound words or we need to ignore extra adjectives/descriptive-words etc.

Adjective/Descriptive-word Example:

> I want to immediately go to the google.com homepage

Compound Word Example (homepage is broken into two words):

> I want to go to the google.com home page

And you can probably imagine even more complicated real-world sentences that should match this one, but won't match or work without some extra cases or additional checks for the sentence.

Obviously our current setup isn't ideal, due to the fact we need to do multiple passes over this string for every individual case we need to check which not only slows things down, but makes maintenance and debugging more complicated than it should be.

Is there a data structure that would be ideal for holding and comparing sentences in this manor? Something that would be fairly fault tolerant to extra or even missing words (within reason, obviously)? I imagine some kind of tree, but I do not know what type of tree or data-structure in general would be the best for this situation.

Thanks to any/all in advance!

Comment: short answer: if there was such thing, speech recognition would be a piece of cake ;-)

Comment: [Proximity Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_search_(text)) ?